# How to fix QGIS fills inner contours of buildings

Tags: qgis, geojson, json

I have a .json file with building contours. I have enabled contour filling in QGIS to highlight the buildings. And for some reason, QGIS filled the courtyards of the buildings. Please tell me how can I fix this? How should the contour be defined so that QGIS understands that the courtyard does not belong to the building and does not need to be filled?
An example of the building contours from image below.

[image: Building with a filled courtyards]

Comment: I guess the definition of the geometry is faulty. You need a ring.

Comment: I'll read about the ring. Thank you!

Comment: The problem was that the contours are linear objects, but should be area objects

Comment: I suggest you selfanswer the question, if you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my contours are linear objects, but should be area objects. After changing the type of contour to area, you can add a ring to it.